# How to unmarhsal nested xml using Jaxb

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, jaxb, marshalling

I have a xml that looks like this, I am trying to parse this so that I can get access to a list of "history"s from the "RevisionList" Element.

```
<vehicleHistoryList ml-update="aware" ml-stage="preload">
   <ExtractInfo date="2011-11-11T17:50:41.011-02:00" requestedRevision="4.0">
      <LoadTimes>
         <entry key="Vehicle History List DAO">1111</entry>
         <entry key="Test DAO">111</entry>
      </LoadTimes>
      <ComponentVersions>
         <entry key="Vehicle List Engine">1.44.1-190949</entry>
         <entry key="Vehicle List DAO">1.44.1-190949</entry>
         <entry key="WebService">1.44.1-190949</entry>
      </ComponentVersions>
      <debug dateTime="2022-11-28T17:50:41.011-05:00" enabled="false" />
   </ExtractInfo>
   <RevisionList>
      <history Acode="111111" RevCode="1227535.0" EffectiveDate="2022-07-25T00:00:00.000" LockedDate="2022-11-14T22:22:12.670-05:00" Latest_Change_Date="2022-11-11T23:11:46.400-05:00" Latest_Status_Change_Date="2022-11-11T18:03:15.553-05:00" />
      <history Acode="222222" RevCode="1192984.1" EffectiveDate="2022-06-14T00:00:00.000" LockedDate="2022-07-25T23:02:06.987-04:00" Latest_Change_Date="2022-11-11T23:11:46.417-05:00" Latest_Status_Change_Date="2022-06-15T07:05:42.470-04:00" Embargo_Date="2049-12-31T00:01:00-05:00" />
   </RevisionList>
</vehicleHistoryList>
```

I want to parse this so that I get a list of "history" elements.

here are the model classes I attempted to create, but I am getting UnmarshalException: unexpected elements error when I tried to execute

```
vehicleHistoryList = (VehicleHistoryList) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(xmlSource);
```

VehicleHistoryList.java

```
@XmlRootElement(name="vehicleHistoryList")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class VehicleHistoryList implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6906338837295291920L;

    @XmlElementWrapper(name="ExtractInfo")
    ExtractInfo extractInfo;

    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "RevisionList")
    @XmlElement(name="history")
    private List<History> history;

    public List<History> getHistory() {
        return history;
    }

    public void setHistory(List<History> history) {
        this.history = history;
    }
}
```

History.java

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class History implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 542831991244445544L;

    @XmlAttribute(
            name = "Acode"
    )
    private String acode;

    @XmlAttribute(
            name = "RevCode"
    )
    private double revcode;

    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(CustomDateTimeAdapter.class)
    @XmlAttribute(
            name = "EffectiveDate"
    )
    private Date effectiveDate;

    @XmlAttribute(
            name = "PriceLevel"
    )
    private Date priceLevel;

    @XmlAttribute(
            name = "LockedDate"
    )
    private Date lockedDate;

    @XmlAttribute(
            name = "Latest_Change_Date"
    )
    private Date latestChangeDate;

    @XmlAttribute(
            name = "Latest_Status_Change_Date"
    )
    private Date latestStatusChangeDate;

    public History() {
    }

    public String getAcode() {
        return acode;
    }

    public void setAcode(String acode) {
        this.acode = acode;
    }
}
```

Comment: no details on "unexpected elements error" ?? ... without this and `ExtractInfo` hard to say.. ([edit]!?;) What about `String ml-update, ml-stage;`? ...best: (try to) get/generate that XSD, then proceed with that... ;)

Comment: Without the stack trace and some indication of which element it's complaining about, we are unlikely to be able to help.